# Thin lines appears between rectangles when the grid control is used to tile them together for windows phone

Tags: xaml, grid, windows-phone-8, rectangles

Below code will show thin lines between the tiled rectangles on the windows phone.  I tried setting UseLayoutRounding to true but does not seem to do anything.  There are more thin lines when code is run using a device (lumina 920 in my case) rather than the emulator but the 720p emulator seems to have more trouble with this.  Is there a simple property that I missed that can fix this? I'm using rectangle scaling to 1.1 right now to hide the line but not an elegant solution especially if the rectangles turns semi-transparent then there are bright spots on the overlapped area.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" UseLayoutRounding="True" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" StrokeThickness="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" StrokeThickness="0" />
</Grid>
```

[image: thin lines between grids]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange display behaviour of Windows Phone 8 device in different resolutions(WVGA,WXGA,&720P)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605003/strange-display-behaviour-of-windows-phone-8-device-in-different-resolutionswvg)

Comment: Would you be willing to perhaps share a screen shot of the behavior you describe for a quick visual for us folks who don't want to go load up a wp8 proj / emulator to see what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing this on WXGA (Nokia 920) and 720p (HTC 8X), but not on a WVGA (Nokia 820), then this is a result with the multiresolution scale factor system.  In WP8, all the screens are 480 logical pixels wide, and we apply a multiplier for each resolution (1.5 for 720p, 1.6 for WXGA).  If you need the layout to be perfect, you have a few options:

- Use a separate XAML for problem resolutions
- Use numbers that round in the same direction when multiplied 1.0, 1.5, and 1.6.
- Set your widths based on the ScaleFactor value

I admit that none of these are perfect, but depending on your needs, sometimes a small change to the values can fix any issues.

An article you can read that gives some information about this can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx